# Web Workers - If objects are passed by value is the memory usage doubled

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Let's say i'm doing some image processing whereby I get the pixel data from a html5 canvas using .toDataURL().

If the outputted array takes up 100MB of memory and I then pass it to a webworker to do some computation, since the object is passed to the worker by value will I now have two copies of this array, thus taking up 200MB of memory?

Comment: That's probably implementation dependant, but as a worker uses a new thread, I think it's safe to say it won't be working with the same object in memory as another thread, so yes, you probably have two objects.

Comment: But the first array will be GC'd soon enough.

Comment: Cheers guys, workers do pass by value because of the separate thread so the question answers itself on face-value. I'm doing some image processing on a mobile device which is using a fair amount of RAM, for the desktop browser i'd usually place this in a webworker, the image data is taking up a fair amount of RAM in the main UI thread though so doubling this overhead even for a small amount of time would kill the process on smaller devices. Cheers for confirming my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid doubling the memory usage, use the
[Transferable Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) based API's.  The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) mention this is a zero-copy operation, so you can expect it will not double your memory usage.

Since it sounds like you're dealing with an array already, this is probably a trivial change of passing the array into `postMessage` twice:

```
var theOutputtedArray = ...;
worker.postMessage(theOutputtedArray, theOutputtedArray);
```

[This older blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast) from the Chrome developers (5 years ago) discusses how it differs from regular message passing, and gives some demo code.

[This slightly newer blog post](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/20/communicating-large-objects-with-web-workers-in-javascript/) from a RedHat dev gives a very in-depth comparison of the performance & stability of three different ways of passing large objects between the main thread and worker threads.

Happy reading.

Comment: Cheers for the post Peter, will have fun reading through those articles this evening!